# Angular2 and Java -- is NPM enterprise needed?

Tags: java, angular, npm

I want to use Angular2 with Java as backend technology and will not use Node JS and NPM server, Do I still need NPM enterprise version as I am going to develop for my organisation ?

Comment: no. you can use them as such as they are MIT Licensed.

Comment: I don't think so, because the code on the production server wll, ideally, be a `dist` folder containing static JS, not Angular code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need NPM enterprise version. You can use NPM for downloading libraries and tools like Gulp, Grunt or Bower for build.

Comment: No, NPM is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven plugin from JNPM (https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM) to retrieve required packages like Angular 2 from NPM and pack into your jar/war. Also you can use JNPM Servlet to host transparent retrieval of resources from NPM and provide to client side.